# Hyperledger fabric 2 equivalent to the old composer query language queries (*.qry files)

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, ibm-blockchain

I am new to the latest Hyperledger fabric 2. Before deprecating fabric-composer, queries into the world state could be made easily and intuitively using the composer query language which had a syntax very similar to SQL. What is the equivalent in fabric 2 of this functionality? Are there any tutorials/samples available that showcase this?

Answer (score 0):

yes, there are. See the Fabric Samples - more here: https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric-samples/blob/master/README.md for a description.

The smart contract samples for Fabcar and Marbles (under 'chaincode' folder) in this repo are good examples to get going with. There are READMEs for those samples too (in their respective sub-folders).

A full tutorial (incl queries usage) for Fabcar is here https://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/latest/write_first_app.html  and also the Marbles example with rich queries here: https://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/latest/couchdb_tutorial.html